# Where is the root device?

Tags: arm, kernel, raspberry-pi, bare-metal

I'm writing a little micro-kernel from scratch for my Raspberry Pi (here's the code : https://github.com/yrakcaz/RasPiK/)

Everything seems to work fine but I have just a little problem : I would like to have a file system, but I don't find out how to get the root device address. I know that, on x86 architectures, we can get the ROM address using the tags passed in argument to the main function, but I already parsed atags and there is nothing interesting...

How can I get this address?

Answer (score 0):

Just choose it. Nothing is mandatory when you are bare metal. Either you get it from your bootloader, (then you have to choose it in your bootloader), or you choose to have a ramfs as the root of your file system, or you choose to use the SD card you boot on as your root file system. It's up to you.

Comment: Thanks you for this answer, but, what I'd really like to know is where is the root partition of the sdcard, because, at the end of my project, I'd like to put binaries on it, then execute it on the rpi. Do you know how I could do this?

Comment: Every *root device* is different.  Now you have said 'SD' card; you assume people know everything about the RPI.  At least for eMMC (I guess SD is similar), there is a special boot area.  Under Linux, you can use `dd if=kernel.bin of=/dev/mmcblk0 bs=1k seek=1` to put a boot image.  There is a partition table.  Then at some offset in the card, there is a filesystem formatted for any of the hundreds of possible file systems.  You need to change the question to SD card only or you are way too broad.  Linux makes them all look the same, but underneath there are dozens of drivers, etc.

Comment: eMMC boot partition exists for embedded requirements only. AFAIK, there is no such thing on SD card. There are two usual ways to use an SD card: using the whole SD card as a single partition, or use it with multiple partitions as it's usually done with an hard drive disk. In this case, the first LBA of the SD card should contain a MBR.